# Why does the filter() function in dplyr return column names instead of the actual result?

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset (called "films") has 20 variables, one which is called "movie_title". When I try to run the code:

```
films %>% filter(movie_title == "Avatar")
```

It returns the name of the columns, like this.

[image: Result of code.]

This is weird, since the filter command works for every other variable, like "director_name" or "duration".

What is the cause of this and how can we avoid this result and obtain the desired result?

Comment: It implies that there is no exact match for `"Avatar"` string.  Check for any spaces i.e. leading/lagging. Try `films %>% filter(trimws(movie_title) == "Avatar")`

Comment: Perhaps try `films %>% dplyr::filter(grepl("Avatar", movie_title))`, perhaps including `ignore.case=TRUE` if you think it's necessary.

Comment: It is not returning the column names themselves (which would look like `[1] "color" "director_name" ...`). The hint from that return value is the `<0 rows>`, meaning that this is returning a `tbl_df` (`data.frame`-variant) that has no data in it. (It is meaningful to have more 1 or more columns but 0 rows.)

Comment: Hi @Esteban . This can happen with beginners. 1. If the filter should show result as per "your" expectations or manual checks, then you need to clean data (as 1 option). So use `trimws` or `str_squish()` from `stringr` on both sides(if matchign name is also a variable/search item in filter -> filter(str_squish(movie_title)== str_squish(searchItem)). this may help. Else let me know and will show a demo data.